# My suggestion to answer every person's question faster

Tags: feature-request, bug

I would say to make the site a better place for everyone,the one answering the question should give possibilities only.Allah works in known and unknown ways.Everyone is on a different path.Some might have easy path,some might have difficult path and some might have somewhere in between.Allah works according to his will.He might bring his wrath,reward or do nothing to a person according to the person's book of deeds.Everyone is on a different path in life and offers advice or answers according to his/her own experiences and understanding.
Also if you get bad advice or low quality answer from someone,we should criticize politely and intelligently or dont criticize .It could be an evil deed.The negative voting discourages good answers to questions.Something alternative should be considered.
Also there should be more privacy and a way to comment anonymously since users are posting very personal information.Separate place recommended for both men and women.